# How to add in data before a link from input box

Tags: javascript, forms

If you see below, my code allows users to input a field with an ip address and it allows them to remote in. Now I have altered it so after the IP it adds information to the link AFTER but I need it to include the http:/ before auto matically but I have to include it in the input box which is what I dont want:

```
<p>Please fill in the box with your IP address: 
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<a href="http://"
    onclick="this.href=(document.getElementById('prog_site').value +
                       '/web/entry/en/websys/atRemote/atRemoteSetupGet.cgi')"
    target="_blank">Let's go!</a></p>
```

I have altered the folowing am I any closer?

```
<p>Please fill in the box with your IP address: 
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<a href="http://"
    onclick=".value + 'http:// ',this.href=(document.getElementById('prog_site').value +
                       '/web/entry/en/websys/atRemote/atRemoteSetupGet.cgi')"
    target="_blank">Let's go!</a></p>
```

Comment: Use http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ if jquery allowed.

Comment: unfortunately not in this instance...I was considering it myself.

Comment: Would changing the `onclick` to `this.href='http://' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '/web/...'` not work as intended?

Comment: @ThorJacobsen That is still not resolving the issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I think I've gotten it to work by fixing some typos here and there:

```
<p>Please fill in the box with your IP address: 
    <input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="" />
    <a href="#"
       onclick="this.href = ('http://' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value + '/web/entry/en/websys/atRemote/atRemoteSetupGet.cgi')"
       target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
</p>
```

A fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/mC4vT/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in rather simpler way.

Create a variable `$link='http://';` and then concatenate the ip picked from the textfield with it and then use the `$link` as final result.